# Calculate contrast of a color image(RGB)

Tags: image, image-processing, colors, contrast

In black and white image,we can easily calculate the contrast by (total no. of white pixels **-** total no. of black pixels).
How can I calculate this for color(RGB) image?
Any idea will be appreciated?

Comment: This question may be off-topic because it's not about a specific code problem.

Comment: Total number of light pixels - total number of dark pixels.

Comment: convert to gray

Answer (score 3):

Contrast is defined as the difference between the highest and lowest intensity value of the image. So you can easily calculate it from the respective histogram.

Example: If you have a plain white image, the lowest and highest value are both 255, thus the contrast is 255-255=0. If you have an image with only black (0) and white (255) you have a contrast of 255, the highest possible value.

The same method can be applied for color images if you calculate the luminescence of each pixel (and thus convert the image to greyscale). There are several different methods to convert images to greyscale, you can chose one you like.

To make the approach more sophisticated, it is advisable to ignore a certain percentage of pixels to account for outliers (otherwise a single white and black pixel would lead to "full contrast", regardless of all other pixels). Another approach would be to take the number of dark and light pixels into account, as described by @Yves Daoust. This approach has the flaw that one has to set an arbitrary threshold to determine which pixels count as dark/light (usually 127).

Answer (score 3):

You may use the standard Deviation of the grayscale image as measure for the contrast. This is called "RMS contrast". See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrast_(vision)#RMS_contrast for Details.

Answer (score 0):

This does not have a single answer. One idea I can think of is to operate on each of the three channels separately, Red, Green and Blue. Compute the histogram of each channel and operate on it.

A simple google search resulted in many relevant algorithms, one of them that I have used is Root Mean Square (standard deviation of the pixel intensities).